# Stop carousel from scrolling when it gets to the end

Tags: javascript, carousel

I have setup a scrolling carousel, that when you scroll with the mouse wheel the carousel scrolls left/right.

When you scroll down the carousel moves right, and when the offset gets to zero it stops it from scrolling. When you scroll up though, and the carousel gets to the end of the carousel it pops back to the beginning. How can I make it so it stops when it gets to the end? I know my math is wrong on my second ternary operator but I am not sure what the math is for it.

https://jsfiddle.net/obo4LkLL/

```
// Stop the scroll from going backwards too far
this.offset = this.offset > 0 ? 0 : this.offset

// Stop the scroll from going forwards too far
this.offset = Math.abs(this.offset) + this.element.clientWidth > this.element.scrollWidth ?
  Math.abs(this.offset) + this.element.clientWidth : this.offset

// Set the offset foreach child in the carousel
this.items.forEach(item => {
  if (!item.style) return
  item.style.transform = `translateX(${this.offset}px)`
})
```

Comment: If Math.abs(offset) is bigger than total_width_of_children_divs (800px) - container width (500px), stop scroling...That should be the math...300 in your case: https://jsfiddle.net/obo4LkLL/1/

Comment: 500px is not a guaranteed width of the carousel. It's usually set to 100% of the parent so it should be dynamic

Comment: Well... you can easily get container width by js, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basic logic is - we need variable limit, which is equal to: total width of child divs in carousel - carousel/container width. To make all dynamic, you can do something like this:

```
class carousel {

  constructor(element) {
  this.total_width=0;


    this.element = element  


    this.items = []
    this.offset = 0
    this.scrollSpeed = 20
    this.element.childNodes.forEach(node => this.items.push(node))
    this.element.childNodes.forEach(node => {if(node.nodeType===1) return this.total_width+=node.clientWidth})
    element.addEventListener('wheel', this.wheel.bind(this))

  }

  wheel(e) {
    // Scroll up
    if (e.deltaY < 0) {
      this.offset -= this.scrollSpeed
    }
    // Scroll down
    else {
      this.offset += this.scrollSpeed
    }
    // Stop the scroll from going backwards too far
   // console.log(this.offset);
    this.offset = this.offset > 0 ? 0 : this.offset

    //stop scroll
    this.limit=this.total_width-this.element.clientWidth;





    if(Math.abs(this.offset)>this.limit) {
    this.offset=-this.limit;
    }

    // Stop the scroll from going forwards too far
   /* this.offset = Math.abs(this.offset) + this.element.clientWidth > this.element.scrollWidth ?
      Math.abs(this.offset) + this.element.clientWidth : this.offset*/
    // Set the offset foreach child in the carousel
    this.items.forEach(item => {

      if (!item.style) return
      item.style.transform = `translateX(${this.offset}px)`
    })
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll('.carousel').forEach(e => new carousel(e))
```

I've just added few vars (total_width, limit) and condition for stop scrolling.

Demo:

```js
class carousel {

  constructor(element) {
  this.total_width=0;
 
  
    this.element = element  
  
   
    this.items = []
    this.offset = 0
    this.scrollSpeed = 20
    this.element.childNodes.forEach(node => this.items.push(node))
    this.element.childNodes.forEach(node => {if(node.nodeType===1) return this.total_width+=node.clientWidth})
    element.addEventListener('wheel', this.wheel.bind(this))

  }

  wheel(e) {
    // Scroll up
    if (e.deltaY < 0) {
      this.offset -= this.scrollSpeed
    }
    // Scroll down
    else {
      this.offset += this.scrollSpeed
    }
    // Stop the scroll from going backwards too far
   // console.log(this.offset);
    this.offset = this.offset > 0 ? 0 : this.offset
    
    //stop scroll
    this.limit=this.total_width-this.element.clientWidth;
    
   // console.log(this.limit);
   
  
   
    if(Math.abs(this.offset)>this.limit) {
    this.offset=-this.limit;
    }
    
    // Stop the scroll from going forwards too far
   /* this.offset = Math.abs(this.offset) + this.element.clientWidth > this.element.scrollWidth ?
      Math.abs(this.offset) + this.element.clientWidth : this.offset*/
    // Set the offset foreach child in the carousel
    this.items.forEach(item => {
   
      if (!item.style) return
      item.style.transform = `translateX(${this.offset}px)`
    })
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll('.carousel').forEach(e => new carousel(e))
```

```css
.carousel {
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border:3px solid green;
}

.carousel>div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right:-4px;
}

.carousel>div:nth-child(even) {
  background: red;
}

.carousel>div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```